# Populating ObservableCollection in ViewModel with Model method

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, viewmodel, observablecollection

I have a ViewModel with a ObservableCollection, SaloonList, which I am populating with data from a database. The below code works when everything is in the ViewModel file:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PopulateList();
    }

    private void PopulateList()
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Uri site = new Uri(_URL);
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(site);
        uriBuilder.Path += String.Format("{0}", "all");
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += SaloonsCompleted;
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
    }

    private void SaloonsCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) { return; }

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DBSaloons));
        DBSaloons jsonResponse = (DBSaloons)ser.ReadObject(e.Result);
        this.SaloonList = jsonResponse.Results;
        e.Result.Close();
    }
```

However, when I am trying to seperate the PopulateList method from the ViewModel and use the below code my SaloonList is not populated even though the list in the action is populated and number of fetched saloons are printed in the debugger window:

```
   public MainViewModel()
   {      
      Models.Fetcher fetch = new Fetcher();
      fetch.PopulateList(this.SaloonList, onComplete);
   }

   Action<ObservableCollection<Saloon>, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs> onComplete = (ObservableCollection<Saloon> list, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) =>
   {
        if (e.Error != null) { Debug.WriteLine("Fetch Error"); return; }
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DBSaloons));
        DBSaloons jsonResponse = (DBSaloons)ser.ReadObject(e.Result);
        list = jsonResponse.Results;
        e.Result.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine("Fetched: " + list.Count.ToString() + " saloons");
    };
```

This is how the method looks like in the fetcher class:

```
 public void PopulateList(ObservableCollection<Saloon> list, Action<ObservableCollection<Saloon>, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs> onComplete)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Fetching...");
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Uri site = new Uri(_URL);
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(site);
        uriBuilder.Path += String.Format("{0}", "all");

        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) => onComplete(list, e);
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, list);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Solved it like this,

```
public void PopulateList(Action<DBSaloons> callback, Action<Exception> exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Fetching...");
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Uri site = new Uri(_URL);
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(site);
        uriBuilder.Path += String.Format("{0}", "all");

        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ((sender, e) =>
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DBSaloons));
            DBSaloons jsonResponse = (DBSaloons)ser.ReadObject(e.Result);
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
               if (e.Error == null) callback(jsonResponse);
                else exception(e.Error);
            });
            e.Result.Close();
        }
        );
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
    }
```

And then in my ViewModel i get the list of saloons like this:

```
       fetch.PopulateList( (list) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fetched: " + list.Results.Count.ToString() + " saloons");
            this.SaloonList = list.Results;

        }, (exception) => { });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = jsonResponse.Results;
```

You're overwriting your reference on list, and therefore MainViewModel.SaloonList and list aren't the same objects anymore. Either replace by:

```
this.SaloonList = jsonResponse.Results;
```

Or manually copy the contents of jsonResponse.Results into list.

Comment: SaloonList is not accessible in the Action.
It's represented through "list" and passed as a parameter in the method call.

Comment: Then copy the contents of jsonResponse.Results inside list with a loop.

Comment: That should not be necessary. Updated my question with a solution.